# como crear un menú personalizado con wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

veran tengo registrado mi menu en el archivo functios.php de la siguiente manera

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu_header' => __( 'Menu header', 'ests' )
    ) );
```

ahora lo que quiero es que la salida de este menu sea del estilo

```
<nav>
 <a>link1</a>
 <a>link2</a>
 <a>link3</a>
</nav>
```

esto es lo que tengo

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3" id="main_menu">
            <?php 
                $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
                if(!empty($menu)):
                    foreach ( $menu as $items ): ?>
                        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="<?php echo $items->url; ?>"><?php echo $items->post_title; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                    <ul id="test">
                        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
                    </ul>
        <?php endif; ?> 
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me auto respondo :) conseguí hacerlo funcionar mediante las classe walker

```
/* class menu walker */
    class Menu_header_walk extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            global $wp_query;
            /*$indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

            $class_names = $value = '';

            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
            $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

            $output .= $indent . '<div id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';*/

            $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a class="p-2 text-dark" '. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>';
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
    }
```